# How do I find an anime or manga only from memory?

Tags: discussion

If you want to find an anime or manga on your own and you remember something about it, this post is for you!

If you have a picture, but you don't remember anything, see [how to reverse-search images](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source) instead.

Answer (score 7):

#### tl;dr

1. Search for "anime" or "manga" + keywords uniquely describing it.
2. If step 1 didn't solve it, see recommendations/similar titles to what you're looking for.

---

#### 1. Search for unique identifiers

Remember the things that uniquely describe the work you're searching. You need something very unusual that you don't see in a lot of other titles. This may come as a surprise, but these keywords will immediately get you the results:

- Mecha robots, angels − *Evangelion*
- TV robot, giant iron − *FLCL*
- Vampire, red round glasses − *Hellsing*
- Police, pistol, criminal − *Psycho-Pass*
- Banana, microwave, time travel − *Steins;Gate*
- Photographer, camera, explosion, cult − *SpeedGrapher*
- Space, garbage collectors − *Planetes*

Of course, there are a lot of works related to either *castles, fighting, vampires* or *detectives*, but if you can remember at least one more distinguishing detail, it will narrow down a lot of results:

- Flying castle − *Laputa: Castle in the Sky*
- Fighting without a sword − *Katanagatari*
- Vampire blonde little girl − *Bakemonogatari*
- Detective dream − *Paprika*

When searching the internet, include the word "anime" or "manga" (or light novel, etc), or you might get a movie or something else non-relevant.

#### 2. Look at recommendations and similar works

If you've found something that looks similar to what you're looking for, take a look at its recommendations and similar works. On MyAnimeList, it would be "Recommendations" tab:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### I only remember the characters

Search characters by their unique traits:

- [Anime character database](http://www.animecharactersdatabase.com/search.php) − **tags**, work type, hair color, eye color, hair length, age, gender, etc.
- [Anime Planet](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/all) − name, gender, hair color, **tags** (select multiple unique character descriptions)
- [MyAnimeList all character names list](http://myanimelist.net/character.php) − name

Answer (score 2):

### I only remember the animals

Anime Planet has a wide range of [animal](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/animals) and other creature tags:

- [Dogs](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/dogs)
- [Cats](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/cats)
- [Birds](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/birds)
- [Rabbits](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/rabbits)
- [Reptiles](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/reptiles)
- [Frogs](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/tags/frogs)

If you don't see the type of creature you're looking for, [look through the full tag list](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/all#multipletags).